# WiringPi: using interrupts with Python

Tags: python, wiringpi, interrupts

I want my RaspberryPi to perform some actions when the light in a room is switched on or off. To do so, I connected a photocell to the GPIO pins.

Previously, I used some python 3 program that queried the GPIO pin in a loop. The code looks similar to this:

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["gpio", "export", "24", "in"])
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys()

last_status = -1

while True:
    current_status = wiringpi.digitalRead(24)
    if last_status != current_status:
        last_status = current_status
        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " -- ", current_status)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This works somehow, but it has some drawbacks, as the code is neither very precise nor resource-friendly.

I think using an interrupt instead of a loop might be superior in every respect. So I tried something like this:

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi
import time

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys()

def print_status():
    current_status = wiringpi.digitalRead(24)
    print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " -- ", current_status)

def start_interrupt():
    wiringpi.wiringPiISR(24, 2,  print_status()) # also tried "wiringpi.INT_EDGE_BOTH" instead of "2" but got the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'INT_EDGE_BOTH'

x = wiringpi.piThreadCreate(start_interrupt())
if x != 0:
    print("it didn't start")
```

However, this doesn't work. I tried to find some examples on how to use WiringPi's interrupt-functionality but I failed - I only found examples for C not for Python (3).

Can you help me to get it right?

I have two questions:

- What is the right way to "translate" the loop-solution into an interrupt solution in Python (3)?
- Is there a way to use `INT_EDGE_BOTH` instead of some integer in Python? This would make the code more readable.

Comment: Have a look into this-
http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-3 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupts are not supported in the python version of wiringPi2 because it's a wrapper of the original wiringPi C library. To quote the publisher of the module in issue [8](https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python/issues/8) of it's github:

> ... I will have to look at implementing Python-wrapped interrupts in a different manner. At the moment your only choice is to set up a polling loop. Sorry!

Try using RPI.GPIO if you want a python module with interrupt support. I think it comes with the standard Raspbian image as well, here's the [Inputs](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) page that has the interrupt function.

If you still want to use wiringPi the solution would be as you have already done, a while loop that pools constantly the desired pin then breaks out when it changes.

wiringPi-python doesn't define the constants like INPUT, OUTPUT and INT_EDGE_BOTH, you will need to define them beforehand referring to them. Those constants are defined in the C library.

Good luck!

Comment: that's bad news... however another solution could be to code this part of the program in C...

Comment: Can you use RPI.GPIO for interrupts alongside using wiringPi2 for other functions at the same time or will they fight?